# Spotfire Rgraphs to table using ggplot

Tags: r, spotfire

I have been trying for a few days to get Spotfire to create a table of charts , which i can then plot on a map chart using lables. I have the following script which works well for the base R hist() plot, but when i change this to ggplot to create the charts i need i get the following error

Error in REvaluate(bquote({
    .(Rfunction)(.(file), width = .(width : Error : `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector

What do i need to do to get ggplot working in this script ( if it can?) it looks like the split function is creating data not usable by ggplot?

```
library( RinR )

irisFrameSplit <- split( iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species )

irisGraphsList <- 
  lapply( 
    X = irisFrameSplit,   
    FUN = function(X) 
      RGraph(
        data = list( X = X ),
        height = 680,
        width  = 680,
        package = 'ggplot2',
        expr =
        {

        hist(X, col = 'red')
        #ggplot(X, aes(x=Sepal.Width)) + geom_histogram()


        } ) )

irisGraphsDF <-
  data.frame(
    Species = names( irisGraphsList ),
    PlotImage = seq( along = irisGraphsList ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

irisGraphsDF[["PlotImage"]] <- irisGraphsList
```

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to add a print statement into the script, use ggplot (so must use print() to make the plot). Since xyplot() includes data argument, RGraph does not try to send over the vectors named in its formula argument.

```
print(

    ggplot(X, aes(x = Petal.Width, )) + geom_histogram())
```